# transitive vs intransitive verbs in relative clauses

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is there a difference in interpretation or how one would understand sentences that use a transitive vs intransitive verb? e.g. in the below

味噌汁を入れたマグカップ vs 味噌汁が入ったマグカップ

> 「でもお前、俺のこと好きだったじゃん」
>
> 「……帰っていいか」
>
> 「逃げるな。いま逃げたらお前の部屋の扉の前で連呼するぞ。お前は俺が好きだーって、寮の子たちの前で」
>
> 「うぐ」
>
> さすがにそれは恥ずかしいんだろう。歯がみする理亜。
>
> **味噌汁を入れたマグカップ**を置いて。
>
> 「……」
>
> 「だった。でいい、教えてくれ」

Comment: I don't feel confident enough to write an answer on this. But there is the grammar point Vて + ある, where V is a transitive verb,  that converts the clause in an intransitive one and means that the resulting state of the action was made on purpose by someone, as opposed to just describing the state of something. For example 「窓が開けてあります」 (the window is open because someone opened it) versus 「窓が開いています」(the window is open). If there's such grammar, I assume there's a difference in using transitive or intransitive verbs in relative clauses.

Comment: Namely, whether there is an agent involved or not. In your example, _someone_ did put miso inside the mug cup.